# Unit testing OSGI bundle

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, osgi, osgi-bundle

How can I test my OSGI bundle? I am using [Kura](http://www.eclipse.org/kura/), which is based on Eclipse Equinox. I am talking about unit tests not integration tests, cause I want to start by checking my application classes and logic before cheking the exported services.

What is the best approach?

1. Include a test directory in the bundle like a regular Java App
2. Implement a new bundle to test my APP_bundle

If 2) is the best approach, how do I link it to my APP_bundle?

What kind of tools can I use? JUnit?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: How do you build your bundle? Maven (+tycho?)

Comment: nope I dont Maven, I export the plugin https://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/hello-example.html

Comment: That example does not look like a good practice. You should try to use an automated build. Unit tests make most sense anyway if they are automatically executed on changes. I hope the kura project also has examples of a professional build.

Answer (score 2):

For plain unit tests you can simply use junit like outside of OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer of a library that helps to write OSGi integration tests. Check this link https://github.com/dpishchukhin/org.knowhowlab.osgi.testing